# Don't reload UIWebView when View Controller is loaded second time

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiwebview, reload

I have `UIWebView` and a button in `HomeViewController`.

When this button is clicked it takes to `SettingViewController`.

But the problem is that when I come back again to `HomeViewController` from `SettingViewController` it again starts `ViewDidLoad` and again reload the `UIWebView` which I don't want.

I want the webpage to persist even if the `HomeViewController` is again loaded.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Have you created segue from `HomeViewController` to `SettingViewController` ?

Comment: Yes I have created segue from HomeViewController to SettingViewController

Answer (score 0):

if the view controller is loaded again, it means it was deallocated before..... likely it was popped or dismissed and nobody retained the view

a) easy solution: don't remove the vc from the view stack

b) 'hard' ;) solution: let somone hang on to it so it is never deallocated -- that is not good design IMO as views shouldn't be cached beyond what UIKit does but that works and it will help old the state.

- give someone an additional outlet to the VC and push and pop that
- use a property on some other VC or if you must on the appDelegate even

=> both ways require you to drop out of pure storyboarding

Comment: thats quite unrelated to the fact that it is loaded twice -- AFAICS

Comment: I did not understood what you said Daij Djan.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing your view while coming back from `SettingViewController` to `HomeViewController` in that case it will call `ViewDidLoad` method in `HomeViewController` and I guess you are loading content in `UIWebView` in `ViewDidLoad` method.

To prevent this
Create segue from  `HomeViewController` to `SettingViewController` and call given segueID from `prepareForSegue` method on your button click

And on back button click just pop your view
(No need to add any code for back button, it will automatically pop your view but if you want you can add `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`)

Load your webView content in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.lipsum.com/"];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webViewDemo loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

Because `ViewDidLoad` method in `HomeViewController` call only once when view added in stack at the same time view pop it will call only `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` each and every time when `HomeViewController` will be at top of the stack

Add a breakpoint in `ViewDidLoad`, you can see

Comment: @PawandeepSingh, I have updated my answer, check now